# How to delete a file that exists

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete a file from SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card)

This should be simple for most people, I want to know how to delete a file in the SD card (`/sdcard/folder`) if it exists i.e?

Comment: [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card

Answer (score 44):

Try this:

```
File folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
string fileName = folder.getPath() + "/folder/image1.jpg";

File myFile = new File(fileName);
if(myFile.exists())
    myFile.delete();
```

Comment: is there a way to revert these files afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

This is accomplished via the `java.io.File` class.  Have a look at the `exists()` and `delete()` methods.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html