# How to delete files from DDMS by programmatically?

Tags: android, file

I've listed the File from DDMS using

```
        final String[] files = fileList();
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, files));
```

Now, i'm in need to delete a particular file from this list. I've a method on Button for to this deleting process `delete_Click(View view)` Can anyone know how to do this with this method(). Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are the files on the SD card or on internal storage?

Comment: @JamesBlack : The files are in /data/data/com.files/files. I don't know what the place is this. I don't know is this internal storage. Sorry.

Comment: I think that is on the SD card.

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem of multiple choice.

You have to look at this

[Click here](http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/custom-listview-ability-check-items/)