# How to delete files in Android?

Tags: android, file, delete-file

I have a file with this path:

```
file:/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/myapp/files/Pictures/IMG_20140108_160223.jpg
```

When I try this code:

```
File f = new File(path);
f.delete();
```

The file is not deleted.
How can I do?

Comment: the problem is that "file:" at beginning. REmove it and it should be work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a similar question here:

[How to delete a file from SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card)

The `file:` prefix seems unnecessary.

try`/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/myapp/files/Pictures/IMG_20140108_160223.jpg`

**Also** you have to give permission if you are using >1.6 SDK

`uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`

in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use

```
file.getCanonicalFile().delete();
```

or even (assumming this is a context)

```
this.deleteFile("string");
```

[More Infos here to delete file with context object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteFile%28java.lang.String%29)

You may also delete your `file:/` at the beginning of your File object creation.