# Rename/Delete file leaves empty file

Tags: android, file-io, delete-file

I'm using the below code to rename a file in Android:

```
File source = new File(SOURCE_PATH);
File destination = new File(DESTINATION_PATH);

if (!destination.exists()) {
    source.renameTo(destination);
}
```

The problem is after renaming the file, there is still a file with the old name in the source folder containing 0 bytes.

I added the lines below to delete the file:

```
if (source.exists()) {
    source.delete();
}
```

But the result stays the same. What should I do?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card about deleting a file ;-)