# Deleted photos in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, photos

I wonder if it is possible to have access to deleted photos or other way to have a listener on the button to remove any pictures?

Or a collector of memoir where I can find a trace deleted photos?

Comment: Divide it into multiple better specified questions. In short, you can't reach deleted photos and you can create button listener to delete selected photos.

Answer (score 0):

Answer1: How to delete photos ?

this depends where the photos are placed, files like photos, audio or video file are generally placed on the sdcard. you can use the code in the following link to delete any file from **sdcard**

[How to delete a file from SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card)