# How to Search and Delete the particular file in android

Tags: android, file, search, android-asynctask

I want  to search a file in mobile which may present in SDcard or else where.After finding the file i should delete the file.Both process like  searching and deletion should be done in back ground without knowing the user .How to implement this can any one help me..

Comment: you need to work on file chooser  and  than a Search functionality associated with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist you have to find the file. Start in root directory, list all entries and compare them with your pattern. If not found, go into each of the listed directories and repeat the process. Keywords: depth first search, recurrency.

You can delete the file using File.delete method. As simple as that. Also, you will need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 1):

for searching the file named "b.html" in folder named "a"...

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/a/b.html");

if(myFile.exists()){
    ...
}
```

and for deleting the file, see this...

[How to delete a file from SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card)