# Delete file on Android SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-file

In my application I can take a photo and save it with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

imageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null),
                        "tmp_image_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageCaptureUri);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

I tried to delete the file from my SD card with this code:

```
File f = new File(imageCaptureUri.getPath());            

if (f.exists() == true) 
{
    boolean state = f.delete();
    Toast.makeText(context, "" + state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The output of the `Toast` is true but the file is not deleted on the SD card. I tested this on Android KitKat but it should work on older android versions too. Do you have any ideas why I can't delete the photo?

I used `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in my manifest file.

Comment: use a try catch block around your code and see if there are any exceptions.

Comment: No exception is throwen

Comment: I found out that it works on Android 4.2 so I guess that it is a problem from Android KitKat. There the API has changed a bit but I think it is all right?

Comment: yes, for android 4.4+ we can only delete package specific files. doucmentation says _"Apps must not be allowed to write to secondary external storage devices, except in their package-specific directories as allowed by synthesized permissions."_

Comment: Yes that's right but I store the file in `getExternalFilesDir`. Do I have to save it in an other location? This is the package-specific directories isn't it?

Comment: check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23761450/3326331).

Comment: Okay thank you. But look [here](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/storage/) in the third paragraph. With the code from above I store the file in this directory but nevertheless it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

With some quick searching, i see that occasionally a call to `System.gc()` is occasionally necessary. Call `System.gc()` after your `f.delete()`

Comment: Thank you for that but I tested it and the file is still there.

Comment: I found out that it works on Android 4.2 (without System.gc) so I guess that it is a problem from Android KitKat. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

KitKat have some changes on how apps can or not access files. Even in the external storage.

Because that's a temp file, I suggest you to relocate it to your own app space like `context.getCacheDir` instead. That will probably work.