# File.delete() function not working in android 4.2.2 version

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to deleted camera captured images using below code but images are not deleting i have tried lot but still no result can some one help me please

### code:

```
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, Constants.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

    private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    File file = saveImage(this, data);
        if(file !=null){
         file .getCanonicalFile().delete();                
     }
  }


 public File saveImage(Context context, Intent data) {

        File mediaFile = null;
        try {
            Bitmap imgBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File imageFolder = new File(sd.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                    "FOSImages");
            if (!imageFolder.isDirectory()) {
                imageFolder.mkdirs();
            }
            mediaFile = new File(imageFolder + File.separator + "fos_" +
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
            imgBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.close();
            return mediaFile;
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mediaFile;
    }
```

Comment: did you check if the image is actually available in desired location file path?

Comment: yes its available

Comment: before calling delete method on file reference please check existance of the file with file reefrence like file.exists()...

Comment: yes if(file!=null) will check that functionality right?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#delete

Comment: not nullability is something else...check for existance as well of that file

Comment: checkd but not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330884/android-4-4-2-not-deleting-files

Comment: Above link some one said that files not deleting is that is true?

Comment: `imageFolder.mkdirs();`. Check the return value as it migth fail. If it returns false display a toast saying so and return. Do not continue as it does not make sensectrying to create a file in a non existent directory.

Comment: Are you getting result? if not, please tell that same file do you want to delete/replace then give some name instead of Curr_Time().

Comment: yes i am deleting same file

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
File file = saveImage(this, data);
file.delete();
if(file.exists()){
      file.getCanonicalFile().delete();
      if(file.exists()){
           getApplicationContext().deleteFile(file.getName());
      }
}
```