# Program is crashing on writing file

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to write some code that keeps track of a few biometrics on an android device.
Every time you press the fourth button the program should output:

```
size1 size2 size3 size4, pressure1 pressure2 pressure3 pressure4, touchduration1 touchduration2 touchduration3 touchduration4, betweentime1 betweentime2 betweentime3;
```

For some reason though when it isn't plugged into the computer and I try and run it on its own, the program crashes the first time you press the fourth button.

I have been debugging it for a while, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work.
I hope that a fresh pair of eyes will be able to help me out.

```
package com.example.joe.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



    /*long pressTime1 = 0;
    long releaseTime1 = 0;
    long pressTime2 = 0;
    long releaseTime2 = 0;
    long pressTime3 = 0;
    long releaseTime3 = 0;
    long pressTime = 0;
    long releaseTime = 0;*/
    long pressTime = 0;
    long releaseTime = 0;
    long pressDuration = 0;
    long betweenDuration = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    float [] array = new float [10];

    double[] sizeArray = new double[4];
    double[] pressureArray  = new double[4];
    long[] pressTimeArray = new long[4];
    long[] betweenTimeArray = new long[4];
    int i = 0; //button number
    int session_number = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        //Sets the spinner

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.Sessions, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        final String Text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        // get EditText by id
        EditText inputTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

// Store EditText in Variable

       final String str = inputTxt.getText().toString();


        //Sets the buttons

        Button Button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button Button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button Button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button Button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);



        Button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {


                    getSizeandPressure(event);
                    pressTime = System.nanoTime();

                }

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    releaseTime = System.nanoTime();
                    pressDuration = releaseTime - pressTime;
                    pressTimeArray[i] = pressDuration;
                    i++;
                    Log.d("Press duration", "time: " + pressDuration);
                }
             return false;
            }
        });

        Button2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {

                    getSizeandPressure(event);
                    pressTime = System.nanoTime();
                    betweenDuration = pressTime - releaseTime;
                    betweenTimeArray[i] = betweenDuration;

                    Log.d("Time between B1 and B2", "time: " + betweenDuration);
                }

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    releaseTime = System.nanoTime();
                    pressDuration = releaseTime - pressTime;
                    pressTimeArray[i] = pressDuration;
                    i++;
                    Log.d("Press duration", "time: " + pressDuration);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Button3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {

                    getSizeandPressure(event);
                    pressTime = System.nanoTime();
                    betweenDuration = pressTime - releaseTime;
                    betweenTimeArray[i] = betweenDuration;

                    Log.d("Time between B2 and B3", "time: " + betweenDuration);
                }

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    releaseTime = System.nanoTime();
                    pressDuration = releaseTime - pressTime;
                    pressTimeArray[i] = pressDuration;
                    i++;
                    Log.d("Press duration", "time: " + pressDuration);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Button4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {

                    getSizeandPressure(event);
                    pressTime = System.nanoTime();
                    betweenDuration = pressTime - releaseTime;
                    betweenTimeArray[i] = betweenDuration;

                    Log.d("Time between B3 and B4", "time: " + betweenDuration);
                }

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    releaseTime = System.nanoTime();
                    pressDuration = releaseTime - pressTime;
                    pressTimeArray[i] = pressDuration;
                    i++;
                    session_number++;
                    Log.d("Press duration", "time: " + pressDuration);

                    // Writes the data to a text document stored in documents on the phone.

                    String filename = str + "_" + Text; //username

                    String string = sizeArray[0] + " " + sizeArray[1] + " " + sizeArray[2] + " " + sizeArray[3] + ", " +
                                    pressureArray[0]  + " " + pressureArray[1]  + " " + pressureArray[2]  + " " + pressureArray[3]  + ", " +
                                    pressTimeArray[0]  + " " +pressTimeArray[1]  + " " + pressTimeArray[2]  + " " + pressTimeArray[3] + ", " +
                                    betweenTimeArray[0]  + " " + betweenTimeArray[1]  + " " + betweenTimeArray[2]  + ";" + "\n";
                    if(isExternalStorageWritable())
                    {
                        File file = getAlbumStorageDir(filename);

                        if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //The output Stead!
                            outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
                            if(10 == session_number)
                            {
                               outputStream.close();
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    i = 0;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });






    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void getSizeandPressure(MotionEvent e)
    {
        float size = e.getSize();
        float pressure = e.getPressure();
        sizeArray[i] = size;
        pressureArray[i] = pressure;

        Log.d("Button_", "Size: " + size + " Pressure: " + pressure);


    }


    /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable(){
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
        // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), albumName);
        if (!file.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Directory not created");
        }
        return file;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only 280 lines of code? Perhaps you need to trim it down to just the problem area!

Comment: Post the logcat information from the crash if possible

Comment: What version of android? Do you restart the program after it has been unplugged, or leave it running and unplug?. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card for more permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declare your permission in AndroidManifest.xml?
like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

or you can pasta the error log to show more information.

Comment: I am not sure where the log file is located if there is one on the phone.