# Android : Delete file from public external storage

Tags: android, file

I'm trying to delete files from public directories (Pictures, Movies, Download,...) on external storage. I have found some similar questions on SO but none of the answers works for me.

Here is the code :

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20131107_142745.jpg");
if (file.exists() && file.canWrite()) {
    file.delete()
}
```

The deleted file is effectively no longer visible in my app but i can still see it with MTP on my laptop. However it seems to be a corrupted file and I can't open it. The only way to get rid of it, is to delete the file manually or to reboot the smartphone.

It works perfectly fine on the emulator when I browse the content with the Android Device Monitor

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/32607757/126125

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `MediaScannerConnection` to scan the file:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
            context, 
            new String[]{fileToDelete, fileToAdd},
            null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code after delete..

(for < KITKAT API 14)

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
Uri.parse("file://" +  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

For >= KITKAT API 14 use below code

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        /*
         *   (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener#onScanCompleted(java.lang.String, android.net.Uri)
         */
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) 
          {
              Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
              Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
          }
        });
```