# Is there any functionality which while installing the android app asks the user about the location where to install the obb file?

Tags: android

I have a resources folder amounting 2-3 `GBs`. I want to install the app with the `obb` in `SD card` directly as some users won't be having that much internal storage.

I am currently searching for the solution.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```

I found out about this which installs the `apk` on external storage, but not the resources.

I am expecting that by default there must be an option in which `apk` is installed in the internal storage while the resources on the `sd-card`.

Comment: AFAIK you can not modify Manifest properties at runtime. So its should either one ..

Comment: You're confused on storage.  External storage != SD card.  External storage is a separate set of directories that can be anywhere but generally are on the internal storage.  In the old days, this set of directories was world read/write (now it isn't, mostly).  The SD card is a different thing entirely.  Yes, this is confusing, and horrible terminology.  Especially since there's now very little difference between internal and external storage in modern Android.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you! Okay, so mostly there isn't any way to install the obb directly to sd-card, unless the end-user is doing it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Well you first need the path the user wants the resources to be downloaded in.
2. Use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) to download zip file of the resource files
   ([You can also check this thread here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog))
3. [Unzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382996/how-to-unzip-files-programmatically-in-android) the files to the select path and then [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card) the the  zip file

**if you want the  resources to be installed by default in the external sd card  first check if they have one for it**

```
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

     //Check for the file
     File appFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
                + context.getString(R.string.app_name));

     boolean exist = appFolder.exists();
}
```

**then just set the path to it**
`if (exist == true){//your code here for the path}`
**though it is not wise as an external storage  does not mean that it is a SD card**